# Programmatically access and read Kentico CMS pages

Tags: c#, content-management-system, kentico

I'm new to Kentico CMS. I have a requirement of programmatically accessing and reading Kentico CMS pages and then expose them in to a mobile app.The current Kentico CMS implementation has form-based authentication and 2FA configured with "Microsoft Authenticator App".

I'm planning to use REST service of the Kentico to get metadata of the pages and then programmatically access the required pages.

Can anyone give me some recommendation for this task?

Answer (score 2):

The REST Service in Kentico uses basic authentication.  You’ll want to create a use to access the REST service.  You can read more here: https://docs.kentico.com/k10/integrating-3rd-party-systems/kentico-rest-service/authenticating-rest-requests

The methods in the REST service should allow you to manipulate your data to get what you need, though if it begins to be too much effort, it may be simpler to create your own hander/service.  You can find out about how to query the data here: https://docs.kentico.com/k10/integrating-3rd-party-systems/kentico-rest-service/getting-data-using-rest#GettingdatausingREST-Dataloadingparameters

Comment: Hi mnield  , As you mentioned I'm planning to use the REST services exposed by the Kentico. The main question what I have is, how would I programmatically read Kentico cms pages when the 2fc is enabled in the Kentico server. My plan is to get the Title and subtitle from the Kentico REST service and display it in mobile app. When user needs more information the plan is to extract the HTML of the CMS page programmatically and inject it in to mobile screen.

Comment: My understanding is that the REST service ignores any 2FA that you have configured and just uses the Auth header when you call the service.

Comment: If it doens't ignore 2FA, you should be able to disable it for the user you create. Use 2FA is a setting on the user account.